# Redirect one jsp folder into another jsp folder is not working in spring mvc 2.5

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a question on redirect page one folder into another folder of jsp pages. I defined `viewResolver`:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"><value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value></property> 
    <property name="prefix"><value>/jsp/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>
```

But My folder struture is

```
WEB-ROOT
      |__JSP
              |__user
                      |_userdashboardpage.jsp
     |__loginpage.jsp
     |__web.xml
```

Iam trying to validate the user details e.g. username, password when the logged the user page using validator interface. But if any error occurs while entered the blank details then occured errors and  redirect the same page i.e, `loginpage` using `getFormView` method with `prefix` property in `viewResolver` bean.

But errors is not displaying in the same page. The container looking `/jsp/loginpage`. But my page having outside `jsp` folder. If iam removing the prefix then it shows errors.

So how to redirect the page one folder jsp into another folder jsp or web-root into `jsp>user>userdashboard.jsp`. How to dispay the error in this scenario. Can i go to chain view resolvers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prefix` property of your `InternalResourceViewResolver` shouldn't go any deeper than the top of your JSP hierarchy. Since not all of your JSPs are under `/jsp`, you can't use that as your prefix.

So remove the `prefix` property, and use the appropriate view names. So to use `jsp/user/userdashboardpage.jsp`, you should return the view name `jsp/user/userdashboardpage` from your controller. To use `loginpage.jsp`, return just `loginpage`.

> Can i go to chain view resolvers.

No.  Multiple `InternalResourceViewResolver` cannot be chained, due to the way the servlet API works.