# How can I link to a web page of another folder?

Tags: html, jsp, hyperlink

My directory tree is given below

```
WebContent(Folder)
      |
      |_____home.jsp(Page)
      |_____User(Folder)
                |
                |_____________deposit.jsp(Page)
```

Below is my deposit.jsp page given
**deposit.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    user deposit
    <a href="~/home.jsp">home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But it can't go to the SendMail.jsp page.So how can I link from deposit.jsp to home.jsp?

Comment: Answer has been already listed in stackoverflow [here][1],


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602090/redirect-one-jsp-folder-into-another-jsp-folder-is-not-working-in-spring-mvc-2-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your **deposit.jsp** page as follows.It will run properly.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    user deposit
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home.jsp">home</a>
</body>
</html>
```